# Kendra does not seem to be crawling our website (incomplete sync)

Tags: amazon-kendra

I have added my organization's website as a data source (webcrawler) in Kendra but after running a "sync" the status changes to incomplete. Looking at the logs in cloudwatch none of the valid pages seem have been indexed. Any ideas on why this is the case? We don't have any webcrawlers disabled for the website.

Answer (score -3):

Answering on behalf of Amazon Kendra.
Sorry for the inconvenience due this issue.
The best way to get this resolved is to reach out to AWS Support. They will help in getting the right attention.